# Android - Framework to walk the user through the new version changes

Tags: android

I'm looking for a framework like the one Android uses when first using the OS. I shows a blue hand and a circle to emphasize on a specific functionality accompanied with a title and some description.
I want to use it the walk the user through the app changes coming with the new version.
Here's a screenshot :

[image]

Comment: Use a ViewPager, 
Great functionality, you must implement it! Once you find any problem in code, get back to us!

Comment: Omg, that's even better. Thanks a lot ;)  
EDIT: I included a screenshot of the wanted framework if anyone else was looking for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found it. It's called `ShowcaseView`
--> [Link](https://github.com/amlcurran/Showcaseview)

Comment: This is something better!